# why sinon stub is returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I am trying to stub a library function with Sinon. Sorry can't post exact code but it looks something like the code below.

The library I am trying to stub library.js

```
async function a(input) {
    // make some api calls here
    returns input;
}
export async function b {
    const output = await a(123);
    // do some magic here with output
    // call again a
    returns a(output);
}
```

My test case file: sinon.js

```
import * as lib from 'library.js'

describe('', ()=>{
    it('', ()=>{
        sinon.stub(lib, 'b')
        .withArgs(123)
        .resolves(123)
    })
})
```

when I run this code my stub returns `undefined` instead of expected output which `123` Can anyone help me find what's wrong I am doing here?

Comment: do you mean return instead of returns?

Comment: also - and I don't know what sinon is - but it looks like in b() you await a call to "a" and get "output" but instead of returning "output" directly you return an unawaited call to "a" again. Seems abit strange to call "a" twice like this, and where you await one invocation of it and not the other.

Comment: @DavidZorychta in the  actual code I am manipulating with output and then calling again `a`

Comment: Is it a recursive function? Might not be the issue but would be good to know if so.

Comment: No, its not a recursive function @RuudVerhoef

Answer (score 0):

I do not claim to be an expert on this subject but it seems to me you are trying to stub instead of mock. Try something like this.

```
describe('', () => {
  it('', () => {
    const mock = sinon.mock(lib);
    mock
      .expects('b').withArgs(123)
      .resolves(345);
    lib.b(123).then((c) => console.log(c));
  })
})
```

This will print 345. Pretty sure there is a more elegant way but this will work.